# SQlite fill empty cells

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am writing this query to calculate.

```
SELECT
Date,
SUM(CASE WHEN (Terms="Sandwich") THEN Stars ELSE 0 END) / SUM(CASE WHEN (Terms="Sandwich") THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Sandwich,
SUM(CASE WHEN (Terms="Chicken") THEN Stars ELSE 0 END) / SUM(CASE WHEN (Terms="Chicken") THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Chicken,
SUM(CASE WHEN (Terms="Meat") THEN Stars ELSE 0 END) / SUM(CASE WHEN (Terms="Meat") THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Meat,
SUM(CASE WHEN (Terms="Others") THEN Stars ELSE 0 END) / SUM(CASE WHEN (Terms="Others") THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Others
FROM __table__
GROUP BY Date
```

Original Data is this.

[image]

This is the result of query.

[image]

/ is used for int division so why the result is in float. Second issue is some times the count and sum of terms is 0 so 0/0 is undefined. I want to fill those cells with 0. Please update query.

Comment: use single `'` don't use `"` , use `'sandwich'` not `"sandwich"`

Comment: @T.Peter Sandwich and other terms are not columns. There are values of Terms column and I am pivoting my table.

Comment: you misunderstand, in SQL we use single quote `'` to indicate string, but double quote `"` will have different meaning in different dbms, but most of it will indicate this should be database idenfiers and which lead to error.

Comment: so you should use `Terms='Sandwich'` not `Terms="Sandwich"` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with conditional aggregation and `COALESCE()` so that you get `0` instead of `NULL`:

```
SELECT Date,
       COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN Terms = 'Sandwich' THEN Stars END), 0) Sandwich,
       COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN Terms = 'Chicken' THEN Stars END), 0) Chicken,
       COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN Terms = 'Meat' THEN Stars END), 0) Meat,
       COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN Terms = 'Others' THEN Stars END), 0) Others
FROM __table__
GROUP BY Date;
```

`AVG()` returns a float.
If you want the result as integers you can use:

```
CAST(COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN Terms = 'Sandwich' THEN Stars END), 0) AS INTEGER)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can just use `AVG` here:

```sql
SELECT
    Date,
    AVG(CASE WHEN Terms = 'Sandwich' THEN Stars END) AS Sandwich,
    AVG(CASE WHEN Terms = 'Chicken'  THEN Stars END) AS Chicken,
    AVG(CASE WHEN Terms = 'Meat'     THEN Stars END) AS Meat,
    AVG(CASE WHEN Terms = 'Others'   THEN Stars END) AS Others
FROM __table__
GROUP BY
    Date;
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have a question, will this average by the count of all rows or the rows with specific term? like `sandwich` is average base on every row or the row with `term = sandwich`?